# Working with Conditions or Assumptions in Mathematica with boolean operators

Tags: mathematica, boolean-algebra

I have the following code:

```
$Assumptions = {x > 0}
b[x_] := x^2
b'[x] > 0
```

In my (very basic) understanding of Mathematica, this should give me me the Output `True`, but I get `2 x > 0`.

I also tried `b[x_] := x^2 /; x > 0` and `Assuming[x > 0, b'[x] > 0]`. I've searched the mathematica help, but without success. What's my basic error and how do I get the desired output?

---

EDIT: The original question is answered, now I wanted to adapt this solution to two variables:

```
c[x_, y_] := x^2 + y
$Assumptions = {y > 0}
$Assumptions = {x > 0}
Simplify[c[x, y] > 0]
```

It follows the same logic as the first case, where I now get the desired output, but why not here? I realize that these are probably typical beginners questions, so if you could explain the logic to me or give me a hint where to read up upon this stuff? Neither the Mathematica help nor my university's (very short) guidebook are sufficient for my understanding.

Comment: Have you tried `Simplify[b'[x] > 0, x > 0]` ?

Comment: Simplify works well on the very first result (2x >0).

Comment: @J.M. and @user9325 Thanks guys... Can you post this as an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Comment: `$Assumptions = {x > 0}` overwrites `$Assumptions = {y > 0}`. Try `$Assumptions = x > 0 && y > 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code

```
$Assumptions = {x > 0}
b[x_] := x^2
b'[x] > 0
```

works fine if you apply

```
 Simplify
```

to the result (2x > 0).

Edit: 
For completeness, I also add the answer of J.M in the comment to the second question.

```
 $Assumptions = {x > 0}
```

overwrites

```
  $Assumptions = {y > 0}.
```

Try

```
$Assumptions = x > 0 && y > 0.
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you by chance also answer my edited question? That'd be great!